# Can Slicers be added to excel using python

Tags: python, slicers

I am automating report generation in excel using python. And I want to insert slicers to excel using python like this image. Is it possible to add slicers to excel using python? Thank you.
[slicers in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Oah.png),
image taken for visualization from https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/slicers-excel-tables